# How to select faulty records?

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

I'm investigating an error in one of our tables of a geographical database. Given the table below, the DistrictName and DisId should always have the same combination (i.e. Bronx = 11, Manhatten = 14), but some records have a different DisId (while still sharing the the same DistrictName).

```
  Id    DistrictName    DisId   Section
  ------------------------------------------------
  1     Bronx           11      1
  2     Bronx           11      2
  3     Brooklyn        12      1
  4     Brooklyn        13      2   //wrong
  5     Manhatten       14      1
  6     Manhatten       14      2
  7     Queens          15      1
  8     Queens          16      2   //wrong
  9     Queens          17      3   //wrong
```

How can I select all faulty records in a query?

There is always a Section 1, so records with a section > 1 containing the same DistrictName but having a deviating DisId are the ones I'm looking for.

I've tried using a group by (districtname) but I'm having difficulties comparing with the section1 record. I'm kind of lost when it comes to putting the logic in the having or where clause. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where section > 1
and districtname in
(
  select districtname
  from your_table
  group by districtname
  having count(distinct disid) > 1
)
```